# Declaring and Setting Variables of Different Data Types in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am currently writing a SQL query which first creates a lot of temporary tables using the WITH operator along with SELECT statements and then joins all of the temporary statements at the end.

All of my SELECT statements that create temporary tables depend on certain filters... so my query looks something liek

```
  WITH 

  table_1 as (
  SELECT  product_id 
          avg(price)
  FROM daily_sales 
  WHERE product_category = 1 
  AND sell_date BETWEEN TO_DATE('2012/01/07','YYYY/DD/MM') AND TO_DATE('2012/30/09','YYYY/DD/MM')
  GROUP BY ds.product_id
  ),

  table_2 as (....
 ),


SELECT FROM table_1 JOIN table_2....
```

I would like to run this query for ranges of 'sell_date' (a date, or a string) and different values of 'product_category' (an integer value).

Currently, I am replacing these manually but I am wondering if I can just declare replace these hard-coded values with variables, which I set at the top of my query.

I understand that this might have been asked before - but I am confused since there are multiple solutions that depend on the exact version of SQL that you are using and the types of variables that you are declaring.

In this case, I am looking for a solution that works in Oracle SQL, and where I can specify the type variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends how you're running your query.

If you're using an interactive client like SQL*Plus or TOAD you should use substitution variables:

```
  WITH 
      table_1 as (
      SELECT  product_id 
              avg(price)
      FROM daily_sales 
      WHERE product_category = &product_cat 
      AND sell_date BETWEEN TO_DATE('&start_date','YYYY/DD/MM') AND TO_DATE('&end_date','YYYY/DD/MM')
      GROUP BY ds.product_id
      ),
```

You will be prompted to supply values for these variables each time you run the query.  If you want to use the same values in multiple places then declare all the occurrences of a variable with a double ampersand - &&product_category - and then you only be prompted for it once.  The SQL*Plus documentation has additional information: [find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#sthref442).

If you're going to run the queries in a stored procedure then define the values as parameters ...

```
procedure process_sales_details
     ( i_product_category in number
       , i_start_date in date
       , i_end_date in date )
```

... which you reference in your query (wherever you declare it) ...

```
  WITH 
      table_1 as (
      SELECT  product_id 
              avg(price)
      FROM daily_sales 
      WHERE product_category = i_product_cat 
      AND sell_date BETWEEN i_start_date AND i_end_date
      GROUP BY ds.product_id
      ),
```

Answer (score 2):

Further to APC's answer, in SQL*Plus or SQL Developer you can also declare variables that you can assign values to in an anonymous PL/SQL block and then reference as bind variables in your plain SQL query:

```
variable v_product_cat number;
variable v_start_date varchar2(10);
variable v_end_date varchar2(10);

begin
    :v_product_cat := 1;
    :v_start_date := '2012/01/07';
    :v_end_date := '2012/30/09';
end;
/

WITH table_1 as (
    SELECT  product_id 
            avg(price)
    from daily_sales 
    where product_category = :v_product_cat 
    AND sell_date BETWEEN TO_DATE(:v_start_date,'YYYY/DD/MM')
        AND TO_DATE(:v_end_date,'YYYY/DD/MM')
    group by ds.product_id
)
...
```

Note the `:` before the variable name denoting a bind variable, and that the strings are not enclosed in quotes with this form. Unfortunately you can't declare a `date` variable, which would make this even neater.

And if you use substitution variables you can `define` them at the start so you aren't prompted; in this case you don't need to use the `&&` notation either:

```
define v_product_cat=1
define v_start_date=2012/01/07
define v_end_date=2012/30/09

...
    where product_category = &v_product_cat 
    and sell_date between to_date('&v_start_date','YYYY/DD/MM')
        AND TO_DATE('&v_end_date','YYYY/DD/MM')
...
```

... which is covered in the documentation APC linked to.

Answer (score 2):

You can add one or more common table expressions to encapsulate these:

```
with
  cte_sell_dates as (
    select date '2012-07-01' from_date,
           date '2012-09-30' to_date
    from dual),
  cte_products as (
    select 1 id from dual union all
    select 28 id from dual),
  ... as (
    select ...
    from   ...
    where  sell_date between (select from_date from cte_sell_dates) and
                             (select to_date   from cte_sell_dates) and
           product_id in     (select id        from cte_products  )
  ...
```

... or use joins directly, instead of subqueries, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Go for an Anonymous PL/sql Block and use a for loop where you can loop through all the different values.

Following is the Structure of pl/sql block:

```
DECLARE
 <constant name> CONSTANT <data type> := <value>;
 <constant name> CONSTANT <data type> DEFAULT <value>;
BEGIN
  <valid statement>;
EXCEPTION
  <exception handler>;
END;
```

Also you can go for a parametrized cursor where you can pass your values.